# Plotting add_trace from within a function: Plotly

Tags: r, dataframe, plotly, lubridate, ggvis

I am trying to "functionize" my plot statements. If i want to add an additional trace from another dataframe, i am getting an error that the values on the y axis do not equal the first number of values in the first dataframe. I am not certain why this is relevant.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly) 
library(lubridate)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2016-10-1"), as.Date("2018-09-01"), by="month")
Values <- c(2,3,4,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,8,9,10,11,12,13,11,12,13,14)

Date2 <- seq(as.Date("2018-07-1"), as.Date("2018-09-01"), by="month")
Values2 <- c(16,17,18)

df <- tibble::tibble(Date, Values)
df2 <- tibble::tibble(Date2, Values2)



testfunction <- function(x, y, y2){

p <-  plot_ly(df,x = ~x, y = ~y, colors = "Blues", type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>% 
     add_trace(data = df2, y = ~y2, line = list(color = 'rgb(255, 36,1)', width = 2.25)) %>% 
     layout(xaxis = list(tickformat = "%b %e"))

      p  
}

testfunction(Date, Values, Values2)

#Error: Column `y` must be length 1 or 24, not 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that `Date`, `Values`, and `Values2` are objects that exist in your global environment. So, `testfunction` is actually using those objects in the call to `plot_ly`. To demonstrate this, try removing `df` in the `plot_ly` call -- you should still be able to get a plot (i.e. `plot_ly` isn't actually using the values in the dataframe).  However, I suspect what you're trying to do is to specify variable names in your dataframe in the arguments to your function.  In which case, try

```
testfunction <- function(x, y, x2, y2) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  x2 <- enquo(x2)
  y2 <- enquo(y2)
  plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
    add_trace(x = x2, y = y2, data = df2)
}

testfunction(Date, Values, Date2, Values2)
```

with a hat tip to this question and answer: [Pass variables as parameters to plot_ly function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760169/pass-variables-as-parameters-to-plot-ly-function)

Comment: @ Weihuang: Thanks so much for your time and help with this answer. It looks like explicitly calling the df2 x axis gets the plot to work.  If i add the enquo() functions to my plots above, the ~ before the x and y variable results in a blank plot. So they must be removed, as you did in your example. Do you know why this is? Thank you very much.

Comment: It's hard to fit the answer in a comment. I would recommend posting your question as a new SO question. It might be of general interest.